# How to set a limited defined random values in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

How to set a limited random values by amount and range in nupmy matrix ?

Means instead :

```
random_matrix = np.random.rand(5, 5)
```

```
[[0.38555213 0.96454126 0.91586422 0.92638243 0.85516641]
[0.64717218 0.2716665  0.70945594 0.74754943 0.48870502]
[0.23381316 0.01992578 0.86749684 0.85797792 0.19308509]
[0.63565231 0.7056163  0.69110815 0.73506642 0.804646  ]
[0.35512519 0.54900446 0.66311323 0.04899527 0.49349834]]
```

the wanted setting for example is 3 random integers between the range 1-5
in a null matrix :

```
0,0,0,4,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,3,0
0,0,0,0,0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like this? ```np.random.randint(low=0, high=5, size=(5,5))```

Comment: Thanks , partly . Only limited number of values are random integers by a range and the others are null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, you want to create a matrix that is zero in all places except for 3 random indices that will have a random value between the range 1-5.

For this i would suggest doing:

```
null_matrix = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=np.int32)

rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = rng.choice(5, size=3, replace=False)
y = rng.choice(5, size=3, replace=False)

null_matrix[x,y] = rng.choice(np.arange(1,5), 3)
print(null_matrix)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It's gives only 4-5 random 1's and 5's and only in the upper matrix line

Comment: Forgot to add the ```np.arange``` in ```rng.choice``` and realized there is no need to combine ```x``` and ```y```.

Comment: Correct , only it should be np.arange(1,6) instead np.arange(1,5) .Thanks again Kevin , have a nice day